# How to handle binary files in a portable way using std::fstream?

Tags: c++

The put/get methods of `std::fstream` classes operate on char arguments rather than ints. 
Is there a portable way of representing these char-bytes as integers ? 
(My naive expectation is that a binary file is a sequence of bytes, 
i.e. a sequence of integers).

To make this question more concrete, consider the following two functions:

```
void print_binary_file_to_cout( const std::string &filename)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios_base::binary|std::ios_base::in);
    char c; 
    while(ifs.get(c))
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(c) << std::endl;
}
```

and

```
void make_binary_file_from_cin( const std::string &filename)
{ 
    std::ofstream ofs(filename, std::ios_base::binary|std::ios_base::out);
    const int no_char = 256;
    int cInt = no_char; 
    while(std::cin>>cInt && cInt!=no_char )
        ofs.put( static_cast<char>( cInt ) );
}
```

Now, suppose that one function is compiled on Windows in Visual Studio, and the other in gcc on Linux. If the output of print...() is given as the input to make...() 
will the original file be reproduced?

I guess not, so I'm asking how to correctly implement this idea, i.e. 
how to get a portable (and human-understandable) representation of bytes in binary files?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do? Do you want to convert binary to text? In general, yes, casting char and int types like you do is compiler- and platform-independent, given that an int on all platforms is big enough.

Comment: The most common human-readable representation of bytes is in hex (base 16) notation. Heavily used in color codes, for example. But also in binary file editors.

Comment: @ ypnos I'm trying to understand how one can operate on binary files. I know how to deal with numbers (ints), but I have no idea how to deal with chars. As to the hex notation -- there is still a question how to do the conversion from byte to int in a portable way (it should not matter if the integer is written as hex or dec)

Comment: A char is *already* an integer. Each byte is an integer. In the range 0…255, or -128…127, depending on how you interpret it. The letter 'a' has a number associated to it in the ASCII table.

Comment: @ypnos Thanks for the answers. But still, the part ``depending on how you interpret it" is exactly what bothers me. In your answer below you also mention that I should use unsigned chars. But how can I do that (in a portable way)? I mean, get() takes a reference to char. put() takes char, but can I assign 255 to char (if it spans -128...127) without causing undefined behavior?

Comment: You can use reinterpret cast to store into a unsigned char, or read from it.

Answer (score 1):

The most common human-readable representation of bytes is in hex (base 16) notation. You can tell iostreams to use hex format by passing `std::hex` into the stream. `std::hex` modifies the streams behavior accordingly both for input and output streams. This format is also canonical to work independent of compilers and platforms, and you do not need to use a separator (like newline) between values. As a stop value, you can use any character outside [0-9a-fA-F].

Note that you should use unsigned chars.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of code out there tat presumes  the char functions will work correctly with unsigned char variables, perhaps with a static_cast, that the forms are bit identical, but the language lawyers will say that assumption can't be relied on if you are writing "perfect" portable code.

Luckily, reinterpret_cast does offer the facility to cast any pointer into a pointer to signed or unsigned char, and that is the easiest get-out.

Two notes top consider for all binary files:

On windows the file must be opened in binary mode, otherwise any bytes with code 13 will mysteriously disappear.

To store numbers larger than 256 you will need to span together a number of byte values. You need to decide the convention for doing this: wether the first byte is the least or most significant part of the value. Certain archetectures (arm native and 68K) use the "big end" model, where the most significant byte is first, while intel (and arm in switched mode) use a "little end" model. If you are reading byte by byte you just have to specify it.